# The integration of Alfresco with Ephesoft 4.0.2

Tags: import, metadata, integration, alfresco, ephesoft

so  i've installed Alfresco community edituion 5.2 and Ephesoft community edition 4.0.2 .

I want to configure Ephesoft to scan automatically to alfresco with metadata ,  (and i dont get the CMIS thing , should i download a CMIS or what for the configuration ) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ephesoft contains already an export CMIS plugin that you can use directly with Alfresco: http://wiki.ephesoft.com/cmis-export-plugin-3